# iPad Loading view and Interface Orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, splash-screen, landscape-portrait

I'm having an issue with my app. I've got an splash with a UIImageView "Default-Landscape.png"  The code is:

```
- (void)showLoadingWithTitle:(NSString*)loadingTitle {
    if(![self.view viewWithTag:123456]) {
        UIImageView *overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        //overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        overlayView.tag = 123456;
        overlayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth+UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        overlayView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];
    }
}
```

So far, so good. The problem appears when I rotate the iPad to Portrait, I think that Portait is loading the Landscape image since it does not look like it should, I don't know what should I do... ¿any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I get it wrong but your code ALWAYS load the Landscape png! I don't see any check of orientation...

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Look at the last line `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];`. You're always using the landscape image.

Comment: the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is just a callback that tell iOS that your app handle all the orientation, but actually it don't do any job for you! you should load different image in response to actual orientation events

Comment: I've got the landscape and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Actually even more simply...

```
  - (void)showLoadingWithTitle:(NSString*)loadingTitle {
    if(![self.view viewWithTag:123456]) {
        UIImageView *overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        //overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        overlayView.tag = 123456;
        overlayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth+UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
            ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) 
         {
        overlayView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];
         } else
{
        overlayView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait.png"];

}
    }
}
```

Comment: For that purpose is better to query the status bar orientation using something like:  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))